# Spring + Quartz resheduling or updating the trigger?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am using `Spring 3.2` and `Quartz 2.2`.

My `target Class` and `method`,

```
public class Producer {

    public void executeListener() {
        System.out.println(" Test Method . ");
    }
}
```

In my spring `applicationContext.xml` ,

```
<bean id="producer" class="com.service.Producer" />

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="producer" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="executeListener" />
  <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    <!-- 10 seconds -->
    <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
    <!-- repeat every 5 seconds -->
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
</bean>


<bean id="mySheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <!-- <ref bean="cronTrigger" /> -->
        <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The above code is working and the `executeListener()` nethod is executing continously with the interval of `5 seconds` and the starting delay will be `10 sec`.

I have tried in `spring controller` to update the trigger as ,

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {

    @Autowired
    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean myScheduler;

    @Autowired
    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean oldTrigger;

    @RequestMapping(value="/reSheduleTrigger.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String reSheduleTrigger(@RequestParam(value="triggerInSec") String triggerInSec ){

        System.out.println("----------------- Changing the repeat interval request -----------");

        // obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
        TriggerBuilder<SimpleTrigger> tb = oldTrigger.getObject().getTriggerBuilder();   

        Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(triggerInSec).build());

        myScheduler.getObject().rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getObject().getKey(),newTrigger  );

        return "success";
    }
}
```

But I am getting the compile time error `Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(triggerInSec).build());` .

**My need :**

I want to `reshedule` the job to execute the `executeListener()` method with the `2 sec` interval dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(2)).build();
```

or

```
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForever(2)).build();
```

Both are syntactically valid. It looks like your issue with `Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(triggerInSec).build());` is caused by incorrect bracketing. ie build() should not have an extra bracket after it, as it returns a trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Works fine.My code is that what in the quartz documentation.The link is http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger . Pls post your suggesation about that.Your code is some what is difference.why ?

Comment: Does the documentation has any mistake ?

Comment: It looks like the documentation for the second example is wrong. It appears to be missing a closing bracket after the .withRepeatCount(10) line. Should be .withRepeatCount(10))