# Spring and quartz integration with dynamic values

Tags: spring

I am new in quartz
I am trying to integrate spring with quartz i want to take repeatInterval and startDelay dynamically is it possible.

```
<bean id="sampleJobTrigger"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
     <property name="jobDetail" ref="sampleJobBean" />
     <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
     <property name="startDelay" value="4000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: you may get help from (http://www.coderanch.com/t/519594/Spring/Spring-Quartz-update-Triggers-database#2353299) or from this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21422521/2749470)