# Quartz job stops firing after Reschedule

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to reschedule a Quartz job like this:

```
TriggerBuilder<SimpleTrigger> tb =  ldTrigger.getObject().getTriggerBuilder();
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(interval)).build();
scheduler.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getObject().getKey(), newTrigger);
```

as explained in     // http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html
  and  [Spring + Quartz resheduling or updating the trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375317/spring-quartz-resheduling-or-updating-the-trigger)

Job **is running** when I make these calls. However, job simply stops firing. What could be the reason?

Comment: All question.. but I have the same situation, do you remmember how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a call to `repeatForever()`:

```
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMilliseconds(interval).repeatForever()).build();
```

If you don't use either `withRepeatCount(x)` or `repeatForever()`, you're telling the Scheduler that the job is supposed to run just once. And since the job is already running, the Scheduler will just stop the job when it finishes, since it has already executed the one time you told it to.

If you actually *don't* want infinite executions scheduled at the given interval, but just one execution after x minutes, just use this:

```
Trigger newTrigger = tb.startAt(DateBuilder.futureTime(interval, DateBuilder.Interval.MINUTE)).build();
```

which seems better suited for that.